# Enable screen capture on Widevine video

Tags: azure-media-services

Using Azure media services, I am presenting sensitive medical videos to three types of users. In order to be HIPAA compliant, the videos are encrypted using DRM. I need one type of users to be able to record the video on the browser and add to it a small section in which they play their comments. I can't do it given DRM prevents me from screen capture. How do I create a policy which enables screen capture?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that you need full DRM (PlayReady, Widevine) to be HIPAA compliant. I would recommend that you look into using just AES-128 Clear Key encryption and avoid DRM altogether.

DRM is built to disable a lot of things like analog and digital outputs, as well as screen recording. That's the desire of DRM - to prevent piracy. You can check with the documentation for Playready and Widevine to see if that restriction can be loosened in the license template.